# PHP/HTML Form not updating MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I can't seem to find a solution to this and i've looked for similar threads too but no luck

Basically here's my code, when you click Update it's meant to display your current name in the form fields then you can overwrite them and submit the changes, however sadly it will not update, it only displays the originally set first name and last name and does not update the database so therefore not displaying the new set names.

```
<?php 
include('../connect_db.php'); 

$res = mysqli_query($dbconnection, "SELECT * FROM users");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);


if(isset($_POST['newFirst']) && isset($_POST['newLast'])){
    $newFirst = $_POST['newFirst'];
    $newLast = $_POST['newLast'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET first_name='$newFirst', last_name='$newLast' WHERE id='$id'";
    $res = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $sql);
}

?>

<div id="editSection">
<h3>Edit Details</h3>   

<form action="edit_profile.php" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>" name="id"/>

<h2>First Name</h2>
<input type="text" name="newFirst" value="<?php echo $row[1];?>">

<h2>Last Name</h2>
<input type="text" name="newLast" value="<?php echo $row[2];?>">

<input type="submit" value="Update">

</form>


</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Kind Regards

~ Matt

Comment: Please don't edit the code based on answers, it makes them useless. Instead accept an answer which helps you.

Comment: @MarcelBalzer it wouldn't let me post again with changes that still caused it not to work, so i updated it for this reason

Comment: OK then try to get a look on the return valu of mysqli_error() or mysqli_errno()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect to DB before updating.so use

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

There are several other errors like you have to make `$POST['newFirst']` as `$_POST['newFirst']` like this

```
if(isset($_POST['newFirst']) && isset($_POST['newLast'])){
```

And change the query to

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET first_name='$newFirst',last_name='$newLast' WHERE id= '$id'";
```

beacuse you have error at end of query `id='first_name='$id'` which is wrong

Comment: Thank you man, just updated it but i'm still having problems with it updating, the connection is within the include at the top to save having to rewrite it every time.

It's definitely connects because it pulls in the current names into the inputs values

Comment: try to print `$res` and see what it displays. if it displays 0 then problem in your query otherwise we need to check php coding

Comment: I did a print_r and i'm getting "mysqli_result Object ( )"

Comment: also try `mysqli_query($dbconnection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error())` instead of `mysqli_query($dbconnection, $sql)`

Comment: was `edit_profile.php` the same page which has html content and php content

Comment: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/folder/public_html/something/sections/edit_profile.php on line 17

Comment: It's all on one page, that code at the top is the full document

Comment: if `id` is `integer` try to use id=$id instead of id='$id'

Comment: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Comment: try this  `id='".$id."' `

Comment: Still getting the same "Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'" problem man. 

It displays the values of what's already in my database but it just doesn't seem to update them

Comment: do you have column named `id` in table ?

Comment: Oh wow, now i feel stupid -_-, my friend changed id to user_id.

Thank you, that did the trick, greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time

Comment: NP, it happens some time.I am glad to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I see some error in the query

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET first_name='$newFirst', 
last_name='$newLast' WHERE id='first_name='$id'";
```

should be

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET first_name='$newFirst', 
last_name='$newLast' WHERE id= '$id'";
```

also

```
if(isset($POST['newFirst']) && isset($POST['newLast'])){
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST['newFirst']) && isset($_POST['newLast'])){
```

Comment: Thank you, i've just updated the post to the changes and i';m still having problems, any idea?

Comment: Try if (!$res) { printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbconnection)); } , this will tell u if u have some error in the query.

Comment: just do print_r($_POST) ; in the edit_profile.php and see what u get before the if condition.

Comment: Array ( [id] => 1 [newFirst] => Bob [newLast] => Artiman ) 
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/solunaga/public_html/bananastaff/sections/edit_profile.php on line 18

Comment: on the top of the page use global $dbconnection ; after the include('../connect_db.php');  ur connection string is not available here so is the issue. Make sure you have included correct file with the path.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$POST` wrong in your if-condition.

It must be called `$_POST[..]`.

Also you should take a look at your `WHERE` in your update query.

I think you mean: `WHERE id= '$id'`

Comment: Thank you! I've just edited the post to the changes and i'm still having problems, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should get your id from $_POST['id']; which is your row ID i suppose and also the update query must be where id=$id.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE users SET first_name='$newFirst', last_name='$newLast' WHERE id=$id";
```

Also have you checked in DB after the update? the row[0], row[1], row[2] used will have old set of values used during select before the update happened. can you have the mysqli_fetch_array($res) after the update call?

Comment: Thank you! I've just edited the post to the changes and i'm still having problems, any idea?

Comment: id='$id' it should be id=$id Hope this helps

Comment: matthew, have you checked in DB after the update? the row[0], row[1], row[2] used will have old set of values used during select before the update happened. can you have the mysqli_fetch_array($res) after the update call?